# Autoremove row in a table after a certain time - JPA Spring Boot

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc, service

Is there any way to implement a service in Spring Boot with JPA that can remove a row inside a table after a certain time? Like one week?

Or will be a very very slow thread be bad practice?

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
public class ConferenceRoom {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private long start;
    private long end; // Delete row after a week have passed from time end
    private String email; // The owner who created the meeting
    private String members = ""; // e.g myMember@host1.com;mySecondMember@host2.com
}
```

Comment: You could use a scheduler like Quartz to regularly run a cleanup job that deletes records older than 'X' (or use it to schedule a job to delete a specific record in the future).

Comment: Do you want to physically remove the the records or simply not see them? In the latter case you can specify an `@Where` on your entities.

Comment: @M.Deinum Intresting. So I only need to put `@Where` at my entity class?

Comment: If you are using hibernate that should be what you need. That way you don't see them (they are still in the db, but they won't come up when you use the `EntityManager` to query the DB, they will if you use plain JDBC or a SQL query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use spring Spring's Scheduled Tasks.

First, mark an `@Configuration` class with `@EnableScheduling` annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

The `@EnableScheduling` annotation tell Spring to create a background task executor. Without this annotation, nothing gets scheduled.

Then create a `@Component` class and start creating the methods that you want to execute and mark them with `@Scheduled`.

```
@Component
public class MySchedule {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 * * FRI") // this method will be executed as 12:00:00 AM of every friday
    public void myMethod() {
        // do your logic
    }
}
```